# How to display an image from XML in jQuery mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, ajax, jquery-mobile

I feel like this has a very simple solution, but I am trying to get this to work for probably too long now.

I've made a function to render an image, atleast that's what it's supposed to do, but it doesn't.

```
function renderAD(entries) {
    var o = '';
    $.each(entries, function(i, v) {
        o +="<img src=" +v.image +"/>";
    });
    $("#adplace").html(o);    
}
```

I checked that v.image refers to http://allroundcars.nl/logo-ijsselmondenieuws.png, which is the image I want to load. But all I see is a `'?' image` (image not found).

What am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated,

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing your each with:

```
$(entries).each(function(i, v) {
    o +='<img src="' + v.image + '"/>';
});
```

**Update:** to add an `<a>` around it:

```
o +='<a href="' + v.link + '"><img src="' + v.image + '"/></a>';
```

Comment: What happens if you just have `o += v.image`?

Comment: @Jef: Are you sure that the variable entries is an array of object that each have a "image" property?

Comment: @Patrick then I am getting the link http://allroundcars.nl/logo-ijsselmondenieuws.png

Comment: Sorry Patrick, it works. I did something wrong, thanks for your help!

Comment: Now I am trying to make a link out of that image: `'<a href="+v.link+"> <img src="' + v.image + '"/></a>'` everything displays fine but I get a pop-up with `error loading page` what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working version:

```
function renderAD(entries) {
    var o = '';
    $(entries).each(function(i, v) {
        o +="<img src=\"" + v.image +"\"/>";
    });
    $("#adplace").html(o);    
}
```